How to change the language of gt html tables in quarto
I want to change the language or the input placeholder in the search bar and the pagination buttons of an interactive table created with the {gt} package within a quarto website.
REPREX
library(gt)

mtcars |>
  gt() |>
  opt_interactive(use_search = TRUE, use_pagination = TRUE)


You can set the locale with gt(..., locale = xx-XX), where xx-XX is one of the available locales found with info_locale().

Edit:
to set a give locale for all calls to gt in the document, here's a (sort of hackish) way to redefine gt for the session:
gt_orig <- gt
gt <- \(...) do.call(gt_orig, c(locale = 'xx-XX', list(...)))

restore with gt <- gt_orig

Great! Do I have to use the locale argument at every gt() call or there is a way to set it as a global option?

You could try setting the document's language in the YAML header like described here. Haven't tried though.

I have, but doesn't affect the table

Is there a way to hide columns in small screens?

Starting with gt 0.11.1, a new option has been added. Setting options("gt.locale") will now set the locale option globally.
